# PHP extract into class variables

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5.3 and the extract() function.

Here is a simple example of a class I am building:

```
private api_username;
private api_password;
private api_signature;
private version = '63.0';

public function __construct($credentials) {
    extract($credentials);

    $this->api_username = $api_username;
}
```

The issue is that after the extract, I have to go one by one through the variables and assign them to the class variables.

Is there a way to extract directly to the class variables so I don't have to do the item by item assignment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the keys of the`$credentials` array match exactly to the names of the private variables, you can use [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to accomplish this (with the key as the variable).

```
public function __construct($credentials) {
    foreach($credentials as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Though, make sure the array you pass in, has the correct keys.

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't safe to do, and the method you're using goes against most accepted models, but:

```
foreach ( $credentials as $key => $value ) {
    if ( property_exists($this,$key) ) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'the method you're using goes against most accepted models' Perhaps. But I have found that PHP is very good about stretching the definition of 'accepted models'.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
extract($credentials, EXTR_REFS);
foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
      $this->$key = $$key;
}
```

Comment: Why go through the trouble of extracting and using double variable variables to get the value, while you have the value in a single variable of your loop?

Comment: indeed, $this->$key = $value;